# Created a custom display form for a sharepoint 2007 list, now clicking on list items takes me to the site root

Tags: list, form

I created a custom display form and set it to the defualt display from under supporting files via list properties in designer 2007. It's set correctly, in so much as going back to the supporting files tab shows what I just saved as still true.

The problem is when I go to the list in question and click on the title, instead of taking me to the display form it takes me to the site root instead.

When I hover over a title from the list in question I can see the link as, for example, "https://blahblah/?ID=14" where as I would expect it to show "https://blahblah/sites/mysite/lists/listinquestion/dispform_custom.asp?ID=14".

So I get that it's taking me to the root of the site because it's a bogus link, but I don't know how I can fix it. I've definitley set it correctly in supporting files!

Any help on this one would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Harry, did you find an answer to this problem? I have exactly the same issue.